# How to solve this SQL query challenge?

Tags: sql, oracle

Can anybody give some idea to solve SQL query with condition like IF user enter transport = 'Bus' or 'van' in transport column in frontend screen, it should fetch data related to entered value.
Or IF they entered spot = 'loc1' or 'loc2' in spot column in frontend screen, it should fetch data related to entered spot value only not other spot.

This should be done using SQL query not with plsql block

```
 --- this is the query i tried
SELECT * FROM transport_tb
 WHERE transport = 'Bus'
   OR spot = 'loc1';

 ---transport_tb table
    Name    Transport    spot
   ------   ---------   ------
   Suresh     Bus        loc1
   Raj        Van        loc2
   Karthi     Van        loc1
   Ram        Bus        loc2
```

Comment: What language are you using to build your 'frontend screen' ? Java ? VB;Net ?

Answer (score 1):

The following query will do what you want:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    TRANSPORT_TB
WHERE
    TRANSPORT = COALESCE(&&TRANSPORT_FROM_UI,TRANSPORT) --'Bus'
    AND SPOT =  COALESCE(&&SPOT_FROM_UI,TRANSPORT); --'loc1';
```

As I am not aware of full requirement, I have used `AND`. Use `OR` operator if needed in your case.

Replace `&&TRANSPORT_FROM_UI` and `&&SPOT_FROM_UI` with actual variable name.

Cheers!!

Comment: I cant understand `&&TRANSPORT_FROM_UI` this statement..please clarify me bro.

Comment: This is the substitution variable in oracle. Please read about it from oracle documentation. This is included in the query for testing purpose. In actual query, You will need to replace it with parameter name which is coming from UI

Comment: Bro.. how did you solve like this complex queries. This there any practice problems for to become expert...please suggest some materials.Because am new to oracle bro...

Answer (score 1):

You can reprogram your SQL query into dynamic query.
You set part of your SQL code to be generated dynamically the moment input has sent to the scripts.  If you are using PHP, implode function can be used into your SQL code.

```
SELECT * FROM transport_tb
 WHERE 

    (transport = 'Bus' OR  transport = 'Van' )  -- dynamic code 
   OR 
     (spot = 'loc1' OR spot = 'loc2')  -- dynamic code
   ;
```

Why this syntax?
(condition OR condition)  OR ( condition OR condition)
With that logic, the OR in the middle searches the possibility between fields. The OR inside the parenthesis searches the possiblity of the values in the field.

Comment: But we cant write subquery in WHERE clause right.. Then how it is possible?

Comment: that is not subquery. That is only making your CONDITIONS dynamic as possible to meet the needs of the user.   If you scripts is not dynamic enough, you'll be end up writing too much codes you're not suppose to.     To acheive that is to rewrite your SQL with dynamic condtions feed on it.     Must apply fail safe code to make you code run if the user didn't give any input.    If you study SQL LOGIC OPERATORS, Parenthesis overrides the LOGIC.